# Шпаргалка для iOS-разработчика (адаптивный дизайн в xcode)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, autolayout

Буду признателен, если у кого-нибудь есть ссылка на ресурс, видео или картинку-шпаргалку, с помощью которой можно посмотреть все разрешения, размеры, типы экранов iOS-устройств.

Узнать, какие `width` и `height` необходимо выставлять для разных ориентаций iPhone/iPad.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [это](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) для iPhone.

На iPad можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.iosres.com/)

Обе на английском, но, я думаю, там все понятно.